# How would I build a game that allowed players to write their engines with resource constraints in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, game-engine

[image]

I want to copy the Scribd developers challenge, but build it using the Gosu framework in ruby. I know how to do most of it, except I'm not 100% sure how to do the following. I'd like a few ideas on the best way to approach this.

Other people (students) will be able to check their ruby code into the repo and I'd like to eventually run all the different bots against each other to determine a winner. Here are my questions about how I would do this.

There is a time limit and ram usage limit. How would you enforce this. Essentially, what I think I want to do is have the game class have a board representation, and then call each engine's `main` method and pass it in the game board. The method then should return a move. If it doesn't return a move in the time limit, then we move on to the next move. Also, there should be a ram limit such that they can't just iterate over all possibilities and store them in memory and essentially store all the states in the game.

Specifically, how can I spawn a process I can monitor and kill in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and RAM are concerns, sure, but the greater concern is security. Running arbitrary user code on your server invites attacks. What's to prevent a user from uploading code that monkey-patches your app code in order to cheat, or send spam from your server, or break things with `FileUtils.rm_rf(__dir__)` or `while { fork }`?

To run user code safely, you must run it in a sandbox. But I'll get back to that.

The simplest way to start (and solve the time/RAM problem) will be to...

#### Run user code in a separate process

Mandate that the user's script must define a class (or module) with a specific name, e.g. Bot, that implements your `main` interface. Write a wrapper script that will take as an argument the path to a user's script and read the board data (as Marshaled data, or serialized to YAML or JSON) from `$stdin`. The script will then `require` the temporary file and pass the board data to Bot. Finally, it will take the output from `Bot`, marshal/serialized it, and write it to `$stdout`.

When a user uploads a script, your app will write it to a temporary file and run the above wrapper script (with e.g. [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)), passing it the marshaled/serialized board data on stdin, then reading and unmarshaling/deserializing the result from its stdout/stderr.

How does this solve the time/RAM problem? Well, since you're just running your wrapper script in a separate process by invoking `ruby`, you can lean on your OS's process-management features, thus removing the possibility of the user monkey-patching their way around those restrictions. If you google e.g. "limit process memory" along with the name of your OS you'll find lots of information. For example, for Linux this tool looks handy: [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout). With such a tool you might run e.g.:

```
$ timeout -t 60 -m 10000 ruby /path/to/user/script.rb
```

#### Security

Okay, so what about security? It's a hard problem, not least because Ruby is so flexible, and so I can't just tell you "this is the solution."

One thing you could do is run all user code in a virtual machine using e.g. Docker. This would make it easy to prevent the user code from accessing your (real) filesystem or the network. (In this case it may make sense to have a simple Ruby server running on the VM that can receive scripts and board data from your app, run the scripts, and respond with the results, since your app won't be able to directly invoke `ruby` on the VM.)

This still leaves a lot of room for mischief, though. It mitigates the damage that can be done by `FileUtils.rm_rf` or `while { fork }`, as you can just spin up a fresh VM, but that's still an inconvenience. To prevent those entirely, you really need a sandbox that reliably keeps the user from accessing methods and modules that could be used maliciously. There's no One True Way to do this in Ruby, alas, but there are some tools and some code out there that will help you get started. Googling "Ruby sandbox" will turn up a lot. One project I've found instructive is [RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/), which is open source and so its code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jwo/ruby-fiddle-exec). It will point you to jruby-sandbox, which does sandboxing with JRuby because Java, unlike (MRI) Ruby, does have mature sandboxing solutions.

I hope that's helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Lots here to digest, but I think the thrust of this all makes since. Thanks for all the info.

As far as the security is concerned, I know all these people in real life, so I could cut their livers out if they mess up my machine. Although, as a safety precaution, I'll for sure run it in a virtual machine of some type.